# c# How to generate big double numbers randomly, with a long tale?

Tags: c#, random, numbers, double

How can i generate random double number between them 0.000000000000000000000000000001 and 0.999999999999999999999999999999, 
So that they do not lose their length after the decimal point when will be printed.

Comment: Doubles do not store insignificant digits

Comment: @maccettura There are no insignificant digits here?

Comment: Doubles only have a precision of 15-16 digits.

Comment: @DavidG not in the OP's example, but OP has asked for:  "So that they do not lose their length after the decimal point when will be printed." which means the length will be cut short if a number is generated that would result in insignificant digits (i.e 0.99 would not be 0.99000000000000 as the OP would expect).

Comment: @DavidG The question is specifically asking for the generated number to store insignificant digits.

Comment: Forget about the decimal point, use large integers and format the string to be printed to add a decimal point. I doubt you will be able to generate random numbers with such precision using standard randomization options though.

Comment: You might have to wait until C# provides an equivalent to Java's `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally generate a string and keep adding random number values to the end, as most number types would not have as many digits as you would like.

```
string Number = "0.";
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++)
{
    Number += rand.Next(0,10);
}
```